# ListView onItemClickListener throws null pointer on scrolling

Tags: android, listview, view, android-arrayadapter, baseadapter

I have a list view where in there are 2 text view places next to each other. Now, this list will have around more than 100 items in it displaying around 10 items in a single page.

Now, as I scroll down the list for all the positions say from position 12 to how much ever it might be, view returns as null.

When I looked for this, got some results of getFirstVisiblePosition(); etc. How ever, I am not very clear on this.

Could any be able to tell me how can I solve this?

Here is my code,

```
  listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
     @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg,View view, int pos, long arg3) {

         View parentView = (View) view.getParent();
         parentView = listview.getChildAt(pos);
        if (null != parentView) {
                TextView dupid, dupdesc;
                dupid = ((TextView) parentView.findViewById(R.id.dupitemId));
                dupdesc = ((TextView) parentView.findViewById(R.id.dupitemIdDesc));
                String duplicateId = dupid.getText().toString();
                String duplicateDesc = dupdesc.getText().toString();
           }

         }
    });
```

When I scroll down say to 20 position,

this line

```
   parentView = listview.getChildAt(pos);
```

throws me null.

[image]

Can any one help me in figuring out?

Comment: your parentView is already initialized. why do you require this  `parentView = listview.getChildAt(pos)` then?

Comment: Because I want to get the view of the particular row item and using that I will get the textview values

Comment: you already have `parentView`

Comment: But that is for whole listview, this parentView = listview.getChildAt(pos); will return the particular row view rt. Can you see the image here?  For example, I want to have the last row in the image

Comment: `listview.getChildAt(pos);` doesnt mean it will return a row(maybe the header or foot or some sort of), so that maybe the childview in this case will NOT be a row.

Comment: Each view in a list is recognized by view parameter of onItemClick method. Once you have that view instance, you can find a subview in it easily and check its value. By writing parentView = listview.getChildAt(pos) you just are wanting the view item of onItemClick method.

Comment: Using `AdapterView<?> arg` you can get the bind data of ListView.. No need of List and its Child view.

Comment: What I am trying to say is, when I click a row in the list shown, the particular line will give me the reference of the row I clicked. This works for the first 10 rows.

Comment: @user370305, can you explain me bit more please

Comment: remove this `listview.getChildAt(pos)` and then give it a try.

Comment: @Raghunandan, give me a minute. I will try this

Comment: Are you binding customer adapter to Listview??? Right..

Comment: Replace View parentView = (View) view.getParent();
parentView = listview.getChildAt(pos); with View parentView = view;

Comment: @random, cool your code is working exactly as I wanted

Comment: @Raghunandan, I tried your code, it doesn't throw null pointer but also it doesn't retrieve clicked position value

Comment: Now, whose answer I should accept? :)

Comment: yes the one you inflate for your row items

Comment: I am using Linear layout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isn't this all you need to do?

```
listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg,View view, int pos, long arg3) {
        TextView dupid, dupdesc;
        dupid = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.dupitemId));
        dupdesc = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.dupitemIdDesc));
        String duplicateId = dupid.getText().toString();
        String duplicateDesc = dupdesc.getText().toString();
    }
});
```